# how to get the values for the data using match function?

Tags: vba, excel

the question is described below:
A is total available tests ;B,C are the tests done on a object and its result; D,E are output

the total tests available are in column A. Column B represents the tests done on an object, so they vary if the object is changed and column C gives the results of the test. D is again output which represents the total tests and E gives the results for the particular tests repectively. i want to give the results in C to E using VBA.and remaining cells are empty. please help me how?

```
A        B           C           D          E                            

qq      qq          23          qq         23 

ww      dde         34          ww

ee      gg          45          ee

dd                              dd

ff                              ff

gg                              gg         45

vv                              vv

dde                             dde        34

ass                             ass

bb                              bb

nn                              nn

xx                              xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should do it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(D1,$B:$B,0)),"")
```

Put it in E1 and copy down. No need for VBA.

For areas outside of USA, one may need to replace the `,` with `;` like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C;MATCH(D1;$B:$B;0));"")
```

if vba is the way desired then:

```
Sub subha()
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
    For Each rng In .Range(.Range("D1"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            rng.Offset(, 1) = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Index(.Range("C:C"), Application.Match(rng, .Range("B:B"), 0)), vbNullString)
    Next rng
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Its showing an error in the formulae, did u tried it_

Comment: @subha Yes, and it works for me based on the data you gave as an example. Now that I think about it you may need to change the `,` to `;`.  See edit

Comment: thank u Scott the vba is working perfectly and could u tell me is it possible to have a dynamic table in vba. the values in it changes and the range is not fixed.

Comment: The vba will process all the values in column D and is not dependent on any certain number of values in B or C.  But it is not live, it will need to be run each time the results are desired.